# Find parent of a declaration in Clang AST

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm using clang to do some analysis and I need to find parent of a declaration in AST. For instance, in the following code I have `int x` and I want to get its parent which should be the function declaration :

`int main(int x) { return 0 }`

I know as mentioned in this link http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.clang.devel/2152 there is a ParentMap class to track parent nodes. However, this just represents a map from Stmt* -> Stmt* and I need to find parent of a declaration. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 8):

you can use AstContext::getParents() to find parent of a ast node。
example code like this:

```
    const Stmt* ST = str;

    while (true) {
        //get parents
        const auto& parents = pContext->getParents(*ST);
        if ( parents.empty() ) {
            llvm::errs() << "Can not find parent\n";
            return false;
        }
        llvm::errs() << "find parent size=" << parents.size() << "\n";
        ST = parents[0].get<Stmt>();
        if (!ST)
            return false;
        ST->dump();
        if (isa<CompoundStmt>(ST))
            break;
    }
```

the AstContext::getParents() can receive a stmt parameter or a decl parameter。

Comment: Have you check this solution? The author need to find parent of a DECLARATION.

Comment: If I am reading the documentation correctly, it is now possible to get the parents of other AST nodes besides Decls and Stmts:

['NodeT' can be one of Decl, Stmt, Type, TypeLoc, NestedNameSpecifier or NestedNameSpecifierLoc.](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ParentMapContext.html#ad75d2749ec4da21d67115e3f6073fd87)

Answer (score 4):

It is exactly `ParentMap` like described in the linked thread that you are looking for. In clang specific declarations all inherit from [`clang::Decl`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Decl.html) which provides

```
virtual Stmt* getBody() const;
```

Alternatively you might also be happy with the [ready-made AST matchers](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html) which make creating queries on the AST much easier. The clang-tidy checks make heavy use of them and are pretty easy to follow, see the sources [[git]](http://llvm.org/git/clang-tools-extra/).

Answer (score 1):

About parent of a FunctionDecl, there something to notice: a declaration of Function may be a member of a class or it may be an "independent" declaration.

If FunctionDecl is a member of a class then FunctionDecl is a CXXMethodDecl so you can check with:

```
isa<CXXMethodDecl>(FunctionDecl *FD).
```

Then you can get the parent of CXXMethodDecl with [getParent()](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CXXMethodDecl.html#afef8b0347180e251310a8c6a55f984a9) method. This method is absent in [FunctionDecl](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FunctionDecl.html).